# JPA Entities for GWT

Tags: gwt

I have developed one GWT project . I have created one JPA entity called Employee. I want that entity to be persisted to the database. My Employee is 
located under com.mygwt.client.bean. Now my question is that are all the entities  meant to be located at server side? When I tried to create under
the server side I got the exception saying Forgot to inherit the module for the Employee. Is there any other way for creating the entities in server side instead of creating the entity in client side? Please suggest the way I am doing right or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in the server side and then add an additional `<source path='..'/>` to your .gwt.xml to tell GWT where the sources are.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is right. But you have to be careful what you put in the packages you add using `<source path='..' />`. The tag `<source path='...' />` in your project gwt.xml file tells the GWT compiler where to look for client side-code to convert to JavaScript. So you can only put classes in there that can be converted to JavaScript. You can not just add the server-side package which contains your remote servlets, that is wrong and won't work.

I suggest the following structure:

```
com.mycompany.client
com.mycompany.shared
com.mycompany.server
```

Basically client code is in the client directory, and in shared you keep classes (transfer objects, models, validators...) which are used client-side and server-side. Then put these lines into the project gwt.xml file:

```
<source path='com.mycompany.client' />
<source path='com.mycompany.shared' />
```

Comment: ok. Thanks. suppose if we want to add the jar files which contains the business logic can we add it in the server side?

Comment: Yes, just place the server-side jar files into WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be careful to access the server library jars only from the com.mycompany.server tree.

Also, not try to send an object from the server libraries over the wire to the client.  If you need to send server library objects over the wire you'll have to have the source to the library -- it's a mess.  It is easier to create a DTO class in com.mycompany.shared that is created my the sevrlet of your application from the server side information.

Stuart